# Pop Up Window Not Display

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, popup

Why the below code is not functioning to registering on html source code?

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "Pop", pops);
```

Below are the complete code. The below is intended to display the popup window. On the other pages, pop up window are displaying using the same line of code. I'm sure that the `ID` of my modal is existing on `HTML` snippet

```
public static void ShowModalDialog(Page page, string modalname = "myModal", int modalwidth = 560)
        {
            string pops = string.Empty;

                pops = "<script language='javascript'>" +
                             "$('#" + modalname + "').modal('toggle').css({ 'width': '" + modalwidth + "px', 'margin-left': function () { return -($(this).width() / 2); } });" +
                             "</script >";



            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "Pop", pops);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "Pop", pops);
```

Answer (score 0):

try by changing your code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "Pop", pops, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the startup script is already registered (IsStartupScriptRegistered) Try the example (you can get it in your language @msdn) [msdn Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/asz8zsxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)